# Why I'm getting Error while converting a column to datetime object while loading a csv file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm just trying to convert a column to datetime object while loading a CSV file in Jupiter notebooks.
Below is the code which I used.

```
d_parser=lambda x:pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %I-%p')\
df2=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Jupyter Notebooks\eth_1h.csv',parse_dates=['Date'],date_parser=d_parser)
```

I got the below error:
FutureWarning: The `pandas.datetime` class is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Import from datetime module instead.

I got an idea that we have to `import datetime` module. But Im not sure what changes I have to make in my existing code.

Comment: `d_parser = lambda t: pd.to_datetime(t, format='%Y-%m-%d %I-%p')` - you could also leave the column as dtype string (don't set parse_dates), and parse afterwards; `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %I-%p')`. That might be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks toRex. I also found the second method easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) instead. Also a function will be clearer:

```
def d_parser(s):
    return pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y-%m-%d %I-%p')

df2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...\eth_1h.csv', parse_dates=['Date'],
                  date_parser=d_parser)
```

You can also handle errors e.g. `pd.to_datetime(..., error='coerce')`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the same tutorials on YouTube by Corey Schafer since the csv file you were trying to read has the same file name as in the tutorial.

The warning actually provided the solution for you already, here is what I did:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

then change the d_parser to

```
d_parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %I-%p')
```

The warning should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, pandas is deprecating `date_parser` in place of `date_format`, so here is a (near)future-proof solution on the line of [Pierre D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758174/pierre-d)'s.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\...\eth_1h.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], date_format='%Y-%m-%d %I-%p')
```